# Prove that for an integer $n$, the bitwise complement is $ \text{~} n = -(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, logic, summation, binary

Numbers in programming languages are represented as binary sequences. All bits are equal to $0$ or $1$ except the *most significant bit* (MSB), which is equal to (has meaning as) $0$ or $−1$. For example, let us consider $8$-bit signed integers:

$$23_{10} = 16_{10} + 4_{10} + 2_{10} + 1_{10} = 00010111_2$$
$$-15_{10} = -128_{10} + 64_{10} + 32_{10} + 16_{10} + 1_{10}= 11110001_2$$

Prove that for an integer $n$

$$ \text{~} n = -(n+1)$$

where $~n$ is the bitwise complement to $n$

For example, if $n = 3_{10} = 00000011_2$ then ~$n$$ = 11111100_2 = -128_{10} + 64_{10} + 32_{10} + 16_{10} + 8_{10} + 4_{10} = -4_{10}$

**Hint**: use the fact that

$$\sum_{i=0}^N 2^i = 2^{N+1} - 1$$

---

I've been stuck on this exercise for more than an hour, and still don't see what to do.

The $-1$ in the hint can be represented in binary as $$11111111_2 = -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1$$

If the N in the hint equals $1$ for example, we have

$$2^{1+1} - 1 = 4 - 1 = 00000100_2 + 11111111_2 = 00000011_2$$

which does in fact equal $3$

I know how to add binary numbers together. I also learned that to find the negative of a binary number, we switch all $0$ to $1$, and all $1$ to $0$, and then add $1$, which is basically what they ask us to prove it seems. For me, this is just an axiom, nothing else, isn't it ?

Do you know how to prove that ? Even just a few hints would really help me a lot. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You should consider that this is assuming ["twos-complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed arithmetic. The result for "ones-complement" is $ \text{~} n = -n$ so there is something more going on than just $n + (-(n+1)) = -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\tilde{n}$ denote the bit-wise complement of $n$. HINT: Note that $\tilde{n}+n=11111111_2 = -1$. Then using algebra from the equation $\tilde{n}+n=-1$, this yields the desired equation $\tilde{n} = -1-n = -(n+1)$, or in particular, $\tilde{n}=-(n+1)$.

Comment: Using algebra: $\tilde{n} = -1-n = -(n+1)$. I edited my answer with this.

Comment: Actually, this exercise they gave us is worth 5 points, which is a third of the total points of the homework they gave us for next week. So I fear that a proof as simple as ~ $n + n = -1$, and then using properties of binary numbers and the sum they give in the hint to show how they complement each others, is too simple, don't you think ? This seems too simple, I don't see why this is worth so much in our homework if it would be so simple than what you say

Comment: Yes, in fact, this makes a lot of sense. But is this really as simple as that ? See my comment above. This question alone is worth a third of out homework for next week, this seems too simple, don't you think ?

Comment: If it's really as simple as that, it seems to strange, do you have an idea how this can be worth so much if the proof is "relatively" short ? Or are they just testing our mathematical understanding maybe ?

Comment: I really appreciate your help by the way, I have been struggling for more than an hour, this forum is really a gold mine for mathematics

Comment: @wengen If you want (or they expect you) to formalize it more, you could start by noting that the complement of a binary digit $b$ is $1-b$. Then the complement of a number $n = \sum b_k2^k$ is $\overline{n} = \sum (1-b_k)2^k$. Add the two and use the hint provided. This is precisely what Mike's answer is doing, just written differently.

Comment: @dxiv If that's really what they want, then I will do so. I really wonder what they seem to emphasise this so much, but if that's what they want. Thank you for your help dxiv and Mike. This forum is really awesome

Comment: @dxiv Just a question, I get ~$n + n = \sum_{k = 0}^{N}2^k$. Using the hint provided as you say, this equals $2^{N+1} - 1$. To be equal to $-1$, this would imply that $2^{N+1} = 0$, is that correct ? Is that due to the overflow that somehow makes it zero ?

Comment: @wengen keep in mind the leading bit is $-1$ instead of $1$, which makes this sum $-2^7+ \sum_{k=0}^{6}2^k$, which is $-1$. The largest positive integer you can represent is $127$ which is $01111111$.